# Google bar chart display day issue

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

My fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vbdy7fLe/1/

I'm trying to use google column chart and display multiple fields of data and by date. But I'm not sure why it doesn't display **02 Jan 2015** and **04 Jan 2015**.

The data is there and here is my **js code** :

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['date', 'person A', 'person B'],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 1), 1, 4, ],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 2), 1, 4, ],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 3), 6, 11, ],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 4), 10, 5, ],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 5), 10, 5, ]
      ]);


      var options = {
          chart: {
              title: 'Meeting by weeks'
          },
          bars: 'vertical',
          height: 400,
          colors: ['#3498db', '#9b59b6', '#16a085'],
          hAxis: {
              format: 'dd MMM yyyy'
          }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing because googles function to draw the chart has decided that there is not enough space to write text on every single column.
Either try the setting for `hAxis.slantedText`or try making your chart wider.